# Кодировка удаленного скрипта

Tags: javascript, кодировка

Такая вот проблема: сторонний сайт генерирует javascript с нужной мне информацией. Информация включает в себя кириллицу, а скрипт выдается в UTF-8. Мой сайт на windows-1251, поэтому вижу сплошные кракозябры. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как "на лету" переконвертировать скрипт.
Вариант "переконвертировать сайт" не катит - слишком много работы.

Comment: @ХэшКод а почему после 3 комментариев к ответу кнопка "добавить комментарий" пропадает? Это второй вопрос уже такой, уточнять приходится в обновлениях, а об этом, как я понял, не уведомляют. It is a feature? =)

Comment: Угу, фича, в блоге описана.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверьте, пожалуйста. Нашел у немцев, поэтому немного не уверен. Но код похож на "тот самый".

```
function decode_utf8(utftext) {
  var plaintext = ""; var i=0; var c=c1=c2=0;
  while(i<utftext.length) {
     c = utftext.charCodeAt(i);
     if (c<128) {
       plaintext += String.fromCharCode(c);
       i++;
       } else if((c>191) && (c<224)) {
       c2 = utftext.charCodeAt(i+1);
       plaintext += String.fromCharCode(((c&31)<<6) | (c2&63));
       i+=2;
       } else {
       c2 = utftext.charCodeAt(i+1); c3 = utftext.charCodeAt(i+2);
       plaintext += String.fromCharCode(((c&15)<<12) | ((c2&63)<<6) | (c3&63));
       i+=3;
       }
     }
   return plaintext;
   }
```

Блин, куда кнопка комментирования опять делась? =/
Еще вопрос, есть ли возможность отследить появление этого div'а? И один ли раз он грузится?

Если один - примерно так (стилем сначала выставляем "display: none;" диву):

```
function decodeBlock(id) {
  var e = document.getElementById(id);
  if (!e || !e.innerHTML) return false;
  e.innerHTML = decode_utf8(e.innerHTML);
  e.style.display = 'block';
  return true;
  }
var decodingInterval = setInterval((function(){ if (decodeBlock('loadede-from-script')) { clearInterval(decodingInterval); } }), 50);
```

Comment: Или вы его как, в голову через <script src="..."> вставляете? у тега SCRIPT есть параметр charset, попробуйте поиграться, если так.

Comment: а еще как вариант (через одно место, но тем не менее), <pre>
&lt;php header('Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=windows-1251'); $str = file_get_contents('http://[...].js'); echo iconv('utf-8', 'windows-1251', $str); exit; ?>
</pre><pre>
&lt;script type="text/javascript" src="/my-little-proxy.php">
</pre>
Естественно, если внешний file_get_contents запрещен, то через сокеты делать.

Comment: Эх-ма, пробовал - не работает в Хроме. И, оказывается, скрипт подтягивает другие скрипты со стороннего сайта. В итоге кодировка правится только для первого скрипта. Те, что он подтягивает, так и остаются в своей кодировке.

Comment: А куда он эти данные грузит? В div какой-нибудь?

Comment: Создает div и грузит туда.

Comment: Спасибо, интересный вариант.  
К слову, проблему удалось решить, связавшись с разработчиками скрипта. Они сделали вывод скрипта в разных кодировках.